# Automatically link/refresh ODBC linked tables in MS Access via VBA

Tags: postgresql, vba, ms-access

Does anybody knows a VBA procedure that automatically link and refresh Postgres linked tables (via ODBC) in MS-Access 2010? It's because I'm looking for a DSN-less connection to make things easier for the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following VBA code will create the PostgreSQL linked tables with DSN-less connections...

```vbs
Sub linkTo_PostgreSQL()
    createLinkedTable_PostgreSQL "public.table1"
    ' repeat as necessary...
End Sub

Sub createLinkedTable_PostgreSQL(PostgreSQL_tableName As String)
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, tbd As DAO.TableDef
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set tbd = New DAO.TableDef

    tbd.Connect = "ODBC;Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=linkedDB;Uid=pgUser1;Pwd=pgUser1password;"
    tbd.SourceTableName = PostgreSQL_tableName
    tbd.Name = Replace(PostgreSQL_tableName, ".", "_", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)  ' e.g. "public.table1"->"public_table1"
    tbd.Attributes = dbAttachSavePWD

    cdb.TableDefs.Append tbd
    Set tbd = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

The following code will refresh the links for any existing PostgreSQL linked tables:

```vbs
Sub refreshLinked_PostgreSQL()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, tbd As DAO.TableDef
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    For Each tbd In cdb.TableDefs
        If tbd.Connect Like "ODBC;Driver={PostgreSQL*" Then
            Debug.Print "Refreshing [" & tbd.Name & "] ..."
            tbd.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "Done."
    Set tbd = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Thopson It works. Just one more question, is there a simple way to very if the tables are already linked and just refresh them